# Not able to view the preview of MS-Word and Excel in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, search, search-results, office-web-apps

I installed SharePoint 2013 on my server and when i search for the Word and Excel files. I am able to retrieve them in the search results web part but when i mouse over the Microsoft Documents i am not able to preview them.

Do i have to install something else to make it work or configure some where to preview MS documents ?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you dont have the Office Web App installed.

In order to enable the functionality you must have a separate farm. On this second farm you will need **Office Web Apps** working properly.

These requirements are important to us for a few reasons. The first is the extra server that is required will most likely drive the cost. The second is that Office Web Apps is requesting the entire document to be converted for each preview meaning that this will not be a very lightweight solution. Finally, preview only works for content accessed through claims based authentication

How to install OWA: http://melcher.it/2013/05/install-office-web-apps-2013-for-sharepoint-2013-with-pdf-preview/